# Reducing the white space about a tick mark

Tags: pgfplots

I have two tick marks on the x-axis: `-\sqrt{3}` and `\sqrt{3}`. I have shifted both of them horizontally to reduce the amount of the sketch of the function they obscure.  (I used the option `axis on top`.)  There is too much white space around the box containing the tick mark `\sqrt{3}`. How do I reduce the white space so that this tick mark does not obscure the sketch?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=5in,axis equal image,axis on top,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-10,xmax=10,samples=201,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-11,ymax=10,
    restrict y to domain=-11:10,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.25cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    extra x ticks={-1.732, 1.732},
    extra x tick labels={\hspace*{-10pt}$-\sqrt{3}$, $\sqrt{3}$\hspace*{-5pt}},
    %extra y ticks={-3},
    %extra y tick labels={$-3$},
    %extra y tick style={y tick label style={right, xshift=2.5pt}},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
/pgfplots/xlabel shift={10pt};
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-9:-1.1789,blue] {(x^(2) - 3)/ (x + 1)} node[anchor=east,pos=0.9,font=\footnotesize]{$y=f(x)$};
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-0.72508:9,blue] {(x^(2) - 3)/ (x + 1)};
\addplot [dashed, latex-latex,domain=-10:10] {x - 1} node [pos=0.9, anchor=south, font=\footnotesize, sloped]{$y=x-1$};
\addplot [dashed, latex-latex,domain=-10:10] (-1,x) node [pos=0.1, anchor=south, font=\footnotesize, sloped]{$x=-1$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pgfplots` way of doing it is put `inner sep=0pt` in

```
ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white,inner sep=0pt},   
extra x tick labels={\hspace*{-10pt}$-√{3}$, $√{3}$\hspace*{-7pt}},   %% -5pt changed to -7pt
```

[image]

You may also use `fill=none` so that there is no white filling.

Comment: This is the graph that I wanted!  Thanks.  (I see that you shifted \sqrt{3} a little more rightward.)  I want `fill=white` so that the tick mark is not obcsured by the graph of the function, the x-axis, and the vertical asymptote.

Comment: @Adelyn Yes, with `-5pt` you get white rectangle's NW tip on the asymptote. If you don't mind that, you may keep `-5pt` instead of `-7pt`.

Answer (score 4):

You could hide the width completely:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=5in,axis equal image,axis on top,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-10,xmax=10,samples=201,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-11,ymax=10,
    restrict y to domain=-11:10,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.25cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    extra x ticks={-1.732, 1.732},
    extra x tick labels={\hspace*{-10pt}{\makebox(0,0){$-\sqrt{3}$}}, {\makebox(0,0){$\sqrt{3}$}}\hspace*{-5pt}},
    %extra y ticks={-3},
    %extra y tick labels={$-3$},
    %extra y tick style={y tick label style={right, xshift=2.5pt}},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
/pgfplots/xlabel shift={10pt};
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-9:-1.1789,blue] {(x^(2) - 3)/ (x + 1)} node[anchor=east,pos=0.9,font=\footnotesize]{$y=f(x)$};
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-0.72508:9,blue] {(x^(2) - 3)/ (x + 1)};
\addplot [dashed, latex-latex,domain=-10:10] {x - 1} node [pos=0.9, anchor=south, font=\footnotesize, sloped]{$y=x-1$};
\addplot [dashed, latex-latex,domain=-10:10] (-1,x) node [pos=0.1, anchor=south, font=\footnotesize, sloped]{$x=-1$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That gives the graph that I wanted.  I prefer to have a little space - not nearly as much as the default gives - about "-\sqrt{3}".  What does `\makebox(0,0)` instruct pgfplots to depict?

Comment: @Adelyn it's a standard latex command, not pgf particularly, that makes a 0pt sized box, try `(10,10)` for a 10pt square box, or whatever size you want.

Comment: I added the command `{\makebox(2.5,7.5){$-\sqrt{3}$}},` and `{\makebox(2.5,7.5){$\sqrt{3}$}}`.  These commands did not give space around -\sqrt{3} and \sqrt{3} as I had wanted; it seemed to only add the extra space on top.  This led to both numbers being pushed away from the x-axis.  And the sketch of the function almost goes through -\sqrt{3} from the bottom.  How can I get both tick marks up to the x-axis as if I didn't put them in a box?  How can I prevent the graph from going through -\sqrt{3}?

Comment: @Adelyn don't worry about it, Harish has answered and he actually knows something about pgf, unlike me:-) I won't be too upset if you move the tick:-)