# plotting discrete signals

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to plot several discrete signals with **pgfplots**. So far, I've done the following

[image]

```
\documentclass[border={10pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,filecontents,amsmath}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
 n   xn 
-5   0.0
-4   0.0
-3   3.0 
-2   2.0  
-1   1.0  
 0   0.0  
 1   1.0  
 2   2.0  
 3   3.0  
 4   0.0 
 5   0.0
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    every axis x label={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north west},
    every axis y label={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor= north west},
    every axis plot post/.style={mark options={fill=black}},
    xlabel={$n$},
    ylabel={$\boldsymbol{x[n]}$},
    xtick={-7, -6,-5,-4,-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
    ymin=0,
    ymax=5.5,
]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\addplot+[ycomb,black,thick] table [x={n}, y={xn}] {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The **first question** is that changing `xtick` doesn't seem to affect the appearance of the axis, how to expand the `xtick`? The **second question** is some signals may have negative values, therefore, the lines will overlap the ticks. My question is is there a way to place the `xtick` above the axis?

Comment: Part 1 is easy, add `xmin` and `xmax` to set the limits explicitly, just like you did for the limits of the y axis. The second part is harder. Do you want to place the tick (and ticklabel I guess) above the axis only in case of a negative signalvalue? I don't know if/how that can be done.

Comment: Without explicitly adding `xmin` and `xmax`, you can also set `enlarge x limit={abs=0.5}` which is what I suspect you want. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294398/set-vertical-axis-limits-above-beneath-the-maximum-minimum-resp-value/294410#294410

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've reached to a satisfactory result. The credit goes to this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123581/individual-tick-label-style-with-pgfplots).

[image]

```
\documentclass[border={10pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,filecontents,amsmath}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
%\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
 n   xn 
-4   -1.0
-3   -1.0 
-2   -1.0  
-1   -1.0  
 0    0.0  
 1    1.0  
 2    1.0  
 3    1.0  
 4    1.0 
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    scale=1.3,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    every axis x label={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north west},
    every axis y label={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor= north west},
    every axis plot post/.style={mark options={fill=black}},   
    xmin=-5.5,
    xmax=5.5, 
    xtick={1, 2, 3, 4},    
    xticklabels={1, 2, 3, 4},
    extra x ticks={-4, -3, -2, -1},
    extra x tick labels={-4, -3, -2, -1},
    extra x tick style={ xticklabel style={yshift=0.5ex, anchor=south} },
    xlabel={$\boldsymbol{n}$},
    ylabel={$\boldsymbol{y[n]}$},
    ytick={-2,-1, 0, 1, 2},   
    ymin=-1.5,
    ymax=1.5,
]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\addplot+[ycomb,black, very thick] table [x={n}, y={xn}] {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

The `xtick` and `xmin` and `xmax` do not affect each other, as a result, just because you have `xtick` going down to `-7` won't make `xmin` go down that far either.

Now, regarding placing the ticks above the axis, this can be easily done for all of them as shown in the example below.  If, however, you want to have some ticks above and some ticks below, then I'm not sure how to do it.  As an alternative, you could have the ticks slightly offset so they don't overlap with the lines.

#### Negative Values, Ticks Above

```
\documentclass[border={10pt}, convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
 n   xn 
-5   -0.0
-4   -0.0
-3   -3.0 
-2   -2.0  
-1   -1.0  
 0   -0.0  
 1   -1.0  
 2   -2.0  
 3   -3.0  
 4   -0.0 
 5   -0.0
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      axis lines=middle,
      xlabel={$n$},
      ylabel={$\boldsymbol{x[n]}$},
      ylabel style={
        at={(yticklabel cs: 0.1, 5pt)},
      },
      xtick={-6, -5, ..., 6},
      xmin=-7, xmax=7,
      ymin=-5, ymax=1,
      xticklabel style={
        anchor=south,
        inner sep=5pt,
      }
    ]
    \addplot [ycomb, black, thick, mark=*] table [x={n}, y={xn}] {data.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

#### Pos/Neg Values, Ticks Offset

```
\documentclass[border={10pt}, convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
 n   xn 
-5   -0.0
-4   -0.0
-3   -3.0 
-2   -2.0  
-1   -1.0  
 0   -0.0  
 1   1.0  
 2   2.0  
 3   3.0  
 4   0.0 
 5   0.0
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      axis lines=middle,
      xlabel={$n$},
      ylabel={$\boldsymbol{x[n]}$},
      % xtick={-6, -5, ..., 6},
      xmin=-7, xmax=7,
      ymin=-5, ymax=5,
      xticklabel style={
        anchor=north east,
        inner sep=2pt,
      }
    ]
    \addplot [ycomb, black, thick, mark=*] table [x={n}, y={xn}] {data.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

#### Tick Label Background

As suggested by Rman, another option is to add a background to the ticks so that they are visible over the graphics.  He also mentions the use of `enlarge x limits` which is a way of making `xmin` and `xmax` bigger.  In particular, `enlarge x limits={abs=1.5}` will automatically calculate `xmin` and `xmax`, and then add `-1.5` and `1.5` units respectively to each value.

Since I don't want a completely white box, I have opted to use a translucent white background so that the line can still be seen underneath.  Also note that `axis on top` is required; otherwise, the ticks end up underneath.

```
\documentclass[border={10pt}, convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
 n   xn 
-5   -0.0
-4   -0.0
-3   -3.0 
-2   -2.0  
-1   -1.0  
 0   -0.0  
 1   1.0  
 2   2.0  
 3   3.0  
 4   0.0 
 5   0.0
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      axis lines=middle,
      xlabel={$n$},
      ylabel={$\boldsymbol{x[n]}$},
      % xtick={-6, -5, ..., 6},
      enlarge x limits={abs=1.5},
      ymin=-5, ymax=5,
      xticklabel style={
        fill=white,
        fill opacity=0.7,
        text opacity=1,
        inner sep=1pt,
      },
      axis on top,
    ]
    \addplot [ycomb, black, thick, mark=*] table [x={n}, y={xn}] {data.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: +1, nice answer, but aesthetically I think using a `fill` for the ticks label (and let them where they are, above or below the axes depending on where most of values are) is much more appropriate... see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211562/reducing-the-white-space-about-a-tick-mark

Comment: ...although I am struggling making the labels in front of the stems. Hmmm....

Comment: @Rmano Thanks for the suggestion.  I implemented it :)