# Discrete-time sequence with labels for individual samples

Tags: pgfplots

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}  
\usepackage{pgfplots}  
\usepackage{tikz}  

\begin{document}  
\begin{figure}%  
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]  
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, xtick={-3,-2,...,5,9},  
      xticklabels={-3,{}, -1, 0, 1, {}, {}, {}, 5, $k$},  
      extra x ticks={-2, 2, 3, 4},  
      extra x tick labels={$-2$, $2$, $3$, $4$},  
      extra x tick style={  
        xticklabel style={yshift=0.5ex, anchor=south}},  
      xmin=-5,xmax=11, ytick={\empty}, yticklabels={},  
      ymin=-5, ymax=6, axis on top]  
      \addplot+[ycomb,black,thick] plot coordinates  
      {(-3,3) (-2,-2) (-1,1.5) (0,4) (1,1.5) (2,-1.5) (3, -3)  
        (4,-1) (5,4) (9,5)};  
    \end{axis}  
    \node at (5.1,3.5) {$\cdots$};  
    \node at (0,3.5) {$\cdots$};  
    \node at (0.8,4.5) {\tiny{$x[-3]\delta[n+3]$}};  
    \node at (2.7,4.8) {\tiny{$x[0]\delta[n]$}};  
    \node at (4.2,5) {\tiny{$x[5]\delta[n-5]$}};  
    \node at (6,5.5) {\tiny{$x[\alert{k}]\delta[n-\alert{k}]$}};  
    \node at (6.8,2.2) {$n$};  
    \node at (2.7,5.7) {$x[n]$};  
  \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{figure}  
\end{document}
```

After some more searching in this forum, I have come up with this code and the associated plot.  The positioning of the things I want is a kludge.

Questions: All the positioning is manual (by trial and error). Even the x- and y-axis labels I had to locate by trial and error.  Can this be automated?  When I change the fontsize for the x-labels (e.g., \footnotesize), their alignmens get messed up.

Comment: May be you could take a look at this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296223/plotting-discrete-signals?rq=1

Comment: If you can draw that neatly, you might just scan your drawing and include it as a graphic.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I had already looked at the links that are being referred to.  My question is about adding labels to the individual stems. If you can provide a link to a post that details how to do that that would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might prefer a more flexible draw-it-yourself approach rather than trying to customise a PGF plot.  Here's an approach using [MetaPost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) and [`luamplib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamplib?lang=en).  Compile with `lualatex`.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
    numeric u, v;
    u = 1cm;
    v = 8mm;
    color pin_shade;
    pin_shade = 1/3[blue,white];

    vardef make_pin(expr X_value, Y_value, label_text) = 
        draw (X_value*u,0) -- (X_value*u,Y_value*v) withpen pencircle scaled 0.8 withcolor pin_shade;
        fill fullcircle scaled 4 shifted (X_value*u,Y_value*v) withcolor pin_shade;
        numeric label_Y, number_Y;
        label_Y = Y_value*v * (abs(Y_value*v)+10)/abs(Y_value*v);
        number_Y = if Y_value > 0: - fi 9;
        label(label_text, (X_value*u, label_Y));
        label("$" & decimal X_value & "$", (X_value*u if X_value=0: +5 fi, number_Y));
    enddef;

    beginfig(1);
    path xx, yy;
    xx = (4 left -- 8 right) scaled u;
    yy = (4 down -- 5 up) scaled v;
    drawarrow xx withcolor .5 white;
    drawarrow yy withcolor .5 white;

    make_pin(-3, 2,"$\scriptstyle x[-3]δ[n+3]$");
    make_pin(-2,-1,"$\scriptstyle x[-2]δ[n+2]$");
    make_pin(-1,+1,"$\scriptstyle x[-1]δ[n+1]$");
    make_pin( 0,+3,"$\scriptstyle x[0]δ[n]$");
    make_pin(+1,+1,"$\scriptstyle x[1]δ[n+2]$");
    make_pin(+2,-1,"$\scriptstyle x[2]δ[n+3]$");
    % etc

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the normal axis labels provided by the `pgfplots` package. To add annotations to your plot, use `tikz` nodes combined with `axis cs` which lets you use the the coordinates you already used for your plot.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}  
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, xtick={-3,-2,...,5,9},  
      xticklabels={-3,{}, -1, 0, 1, {}, {}, {}, 5, $k$},  
      extra x ticks={-2, 2, 3, 4},  
      extra x tick labels={$-2$, $2$, $3$, $4$},  
      extra x tick style={  
        xticklabel style={yshift=0.5ex, anchor=south}},  
      xmin=-5,xmax=11, ytick={\empty}, yticklabels={},  
      ymin=-5, ymax=6, axis on top,
      % axis labels
      xlabel={$n$}, x label style={anchor=north},
      ylabel={$x[n]$}, y label style={anchor=west}]  
      \addplot+[ycomb,black,thick] plot coordinates  
      {(-3,3) (-2,-2) (-1,1.5) (0,4) (1,1.5) (2,-1.5) (3, -3)  
        (4,-1) (5,4) (9,5)};

      % point labels
      \node[anchor=south] at (axis cs:-3,3) {\tiny{$x[-3]\delta[n+3]$}};
      \node[anchor=south west] at (axis cs:0,4) {\tiny{$x[0]\delta[n]$}};  
      \node[anchor=south] at (axis cs:5,4) {\tiny{$x[5]\delta[n-5]$}};  
      \node[anchor=south] at (axis cs:9,5) {\tiny{$x[\alert{k}]\delta[n-\alert{k}]$}};

      % alternative positioning for cdots
      \node at (axis cs:-4.5,1.75) {$\cdots$};
      \node at (axis cs:7.5,1.75) {$\cdots$};
    \end{axis}   
  \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```